# WebKitView not adhering to auto layout rules

Tags: swift, uiview, wkwebview

I'd like to place a `WKWebView` in a `UIView`, with some padding around. Let's say 50 pixels. Here's what this looks like in Interface Builder:

[image: Interface builder screenshot]

Unfortunately the app doesn't behave as expected when run:

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var webView: WebView!
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let url = "http://apple.com"
        webView.loadUrl(string: url)
    }
}
class WebView: WKWebView {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        if let _view = UIView(coder: coder) {
            super.init(frame: _view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
            autoresizingMask = _view.autoresizingMask
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    func loadUrl(string: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: string) {
            load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
}
```

What might cause this kind of issue, and how might I fix it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're setting this in Storyboard just remove the `required init?(coder: NSCoder)`

or use:

```
   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
```

Comment: Perfect - I think I must have sourced the code from another question on here and not realised I could do it without that bit.